# Main() doesn't want to access a class variable

Tags: c#, class, variables, scope, methods

Why I can access to X variable from "method()" and not from Main() method?

```
    class Program
    {
        int X;  // this is the variable I want access

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int a;
            a = X; // this doesnt work, but why?
        }
        void metodo()
        {
            int b;
            b = X; //this works, but why?
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try

```
static int X
```

`X` is an instance variable, which means that each and every instance of your class will have their own version of `X`. Main however, is a static method, which means, that there is only one Main for all instances of the `Program` class, so it makes no sense for it to access `X`, since there might be multiple X's or there might be none at all, if no `Program` instances are created.

Making X itself static, means that all `Program` instances will share `X`, so the shared method will be able to access it.

Answer (score 5):

Main() is a static function. Non-static variables cannot be accessed from static functions.

Answer (score 4):

Pretend you have a Person class with two variables:

- eye colour
- number of eyes

The number of eyes belongs to the class (static) while the eye colour belongs to each instance.

If you change the number of eyes from 2 to 3 then every person in the world would instantly have 3 eyes because all of the instances share the same static variable.

If you change the eye colour of an instance of a person from blue to red then only that individual person will have red eyes.

If you were able to access non-static members inside of a static method what value would it take?  Since there is no sane answer to that it is not allowed to happen.

Answer (score 3):

Both `X` and `metodo()` are at the instance level. `Main()` is at the static level. If you want `X` to be available for both `Main()` and `metodo` you would need to declare it as static (i.e. `private static int X`).

Answer (score 2):

`X` is an instance variable, but `Main` is a static method, i.e. it's not associated with any particular instance of `class Program`.

Answer (score 0):

To have access to X you need either mark it by static keyword or create instance of Program class:

1.

```
static int X
```

2.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int a;
            var program = new Program();
            a = program.X; 
        }
```

You should read more on class's members and on members of the class's instance.